# Can I create a custom @Database for RoomDatabase that use @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) for get annotation on runtime

Tags: database, annotations, android-room

I need to get all entities in my big project that have too many entities, I'm trying to get that by using annotation, but the original @Database is always null on runtime. So I do not know how to solve

Can I create a custom @Database for RoomDatabase that uses @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) to get annotation on runtime? Or any solvent else, I need a `Map<String, Class>` to store the table name and Entity class